# Joint Density Function of two uniform distributions with two discrete cases

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution, density-function

Let there be two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. With probability $\gamma$, they are *perfectly correlated* and each distributed uniformly on the interval $[0,1]$. With probability $1-\gamma$, they are *independent* and each distributed uniformly on the interval $[0,1]$.

1. What is the joint density function? i.e. $f(x_1,x_2)$?
2. What is the distribution function? i.e. $Prob(X_1 \leq x_1, X_2 \leq x_2):=F(x_1,x_2)$?
3. What is the conditional distribution function? i.e. $Prob(X_1 \leq x_1|x_2):=F(x_1|x_2)$?

For 1), I tried something like
\begin{align}
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1  &\text{  if  } x=y \\
1-\gamma &\text{ if } x\neq y
\end{cases}
\end{align}

However, it does not seems right. Because when I do the integration (let $A=\{(a,b)\in [0,1]^2:a=b \}$)

\begin{align}
&\int\int_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2}f(x,y)dxdy\\
=& \int\int_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2 \setminus A}f(x,y)dxdy + \int\int_{(x,y)\in  A }f(x,y)dxdy \\
=& \int\int_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2 \setminus A}(1- \gamma) dxdy + \int\int_{(x,y)\in  A }1 dxdy \\
\end{align}

where $\int\int_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2 \setminus A} (1- \gamma) dxdy =(1- \gamma)$ ? and $\int\int_{(x,y)\in  A }1 dxdy =0$?

If it is true, it does not add up to 1... I don't know where it goes wrong....

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Hint: Use the Law of Total Probability.  Hint 2: Consider the cases $x_1=x_2$ and $x_1\neq x_2$.

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks for your help! I actually tried... I edited the question. I still have trouble....

Comment: You will not obtain a true pdf, as the distribution will be jointly uniform over the joint domain except for a massive spike along the diagonal.  This is a job for the Dirac Delta function.

Comment: So how much progress have you made? @PaulH.Y.Cheung   [Also which definition of conditional distribution function are you using: $~\mathsf P(X_1\leq x\mid X_2=y)~$ or $~\mathsf P(X_1\leq x\mid X_2\leq y)~$ ? ]

Comment: **Hint:** when $\langle x,y\rangle\in[0..1]^2$ then $\int_0^x\int_0^y \delta(s-t)\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d t = \min\{x,y\}$

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint and following-up! I appreciate it. I am now convinced that the distribution does not have a pdf. 

For conditional distribution function, I am thinking $X_2=x_2$. I think it might look like
\begin{align*}
F(x_1|x_2)=\begin{cases}
\gamma + (1-\gamma)x_1 & \text{ if } x_1 \geq x_2 \\ 
(1-\gamma)x_1 & \text{ if } x_1 < x_2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

For the distribution function, is it something like


$$F(x_1,x_2)=\gamma \min\{x_1,x_2\} + (1-\gamma)x_1x_2 ?$$

Comment: The idea of $\min$ is kind of coming from your hint. I just check the wikipedia page about Dirac Delta function. It looks like it is related to the $\textbf{Hint:}$ that you wrote! I think you are probably saying there is a way to approximate the pdf using the limit of the some function such that the limit of that function will be almost everywhere close to the pdf I look for?